Vision SwiftUI - Detected landmarks and connection are drawn correctly only on iPhone without ignoring safe area
I'm trying to personalize an example published by Apple on developer site:
Detecting animal body poses with Vision
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting-animal-body-poses-with-vision
After some tests I saw that the landmarks and connection drawings work only if I do not ignore the safe area, if I do not consider it or use the app on the iPad the drawings are no longer applied correctly.
In the example Apple use Geometry reader to detect the size of the view:
...

ZStack {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        AnimalSkeletonView(animalJoint: animalJoint, size: geo.size)
    }
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

...

with:
struct AnimalSkeletonView: View {
    // Get the animal joint locations.
    @StateObject var animalJoint = AnimalPoseDetector()
    var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        DisplayView(animalJoint: animalJoint)
        if animalJoint.animalBodyParts.isEmpty == false {
            // Draw the skeleton of the animal.
            // Iterate over all recognized points and connect the joints.
            ZStack {
                ZStack {
                    // left head
                    if let nose = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.nose] {
                        if let leftEye = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftEye] {
                            Line(points: [nose.location, leftEye.location], size: size)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                            .fill(Color.orange)
                        }
                    }
                    if let leftEye = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftEye] {
                        if let leftEarBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftEarBottom] {
                            Line(points: [leftEye.location, leftEarBottom.location], size: size)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                .fill(Color.orange)
                        }
                    }
                    if let leftEarBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftEarBottom] {
                        if let leftEarMiddle = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftEarMiddle] {
                            if let leftEarTop = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftEarTop] {
                                    Line(points: [leftEarBottom.location, leftEarMiddle.location,
                                                  leftEarTop.location], size: size)
                                                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                                        .fill(Color.orange)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // right head
                    if let nose = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.nose] {
                        if let rightEye = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightEye] {
                            Line(points: [nose.location, rightEye.location], size: size)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                            .fill(Color.orange)
                        }
                    }
                    if let rightEye = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightEye] {
                        if let rightEarBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightEarBottom] {
                            Line(points: [rightEye.location, rightEarBottom.location], size: size)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                .fill(Color.orange)
                        }
                    }
                    if let rightEarBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightEarBottom] {
                        if let rightEarMiddle = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightEarMiddle] {
                            if let rightEarTop = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightEarTop] {
                                    Line(points: [rightEarBottom.location, rightEarMiddle.location,
                                          rightEarTop.location], size: size)
                                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                        .fill(Color.orange)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // trunk - Draw a line from the nose to the neck.
                    if let nose = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.nose] {
                        if let neck = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.neck] {
                            Line(points: [nose.location, neck.location], size: size)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                .fill(Color.yellow)
                        }
                    }
                    // tail - Draw a line from the neck to the bottom tail.
                    if let neck = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.neck] {
                        if let tailBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.tailBottom] {
                            Line(points: [neck.location,
                                          tailBottom.location], size: size)
                                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                        .fill(Color.green)
                        }
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    // left forelegs
                    if let neck = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.neck] {
                        if let leftFrontElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftFrontElbow] {
                            Line(points: [neck.location, leftFrontElbow.location], size: size)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                            .fill(Color.purple)
                        }
                    }
                    if let leftFrontElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftFrontElbow] {
                        if let leftFrontKnee = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftFrontKnee] {
                            if let leftFrontPaw = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftFrontPaw] {
                                Line(points: [leftFrontElbow.location, leftFrontKnee.location, leftFrontPaw.location], size: size)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                    .fill(Color.purple)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // right forelegs
                    if let neck = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.neck] {
                        if let rightFrontElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightFrontElbow] {
                            Line(points: [neck.location, rightFrontElbow.location], size: size)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                            .fill(Color.purple)
                        }
                    }
                    if let rightFrontElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightFrontElbow] {
                        if let rightFrontKnee = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightFrontKnee] {
                            if let rightFrontPaw = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightFrontPaw] {
                                Line(points: [rightFrontElbow.location, rightFrontKnee.location, rightFrontPaw.location], size: size)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                    .fill(Color.purple)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // left hindlegs
                    if let tailBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.tailBottom] {
                        if let leftBackElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftBackElbow] {
                            Line(points: [tailBottom.location, leftBackElbow.location], size: size)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    if let leftBackElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftBackElbow] {
                        if let leftBackKnee = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftBackKnee] {
                            if let leftBackPaw = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.leftBackPaw] {
                                Line(points: [leftBackElbow.location, leftBackKnee.location, leftBackPaw.location], size: size)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // right hindlegs
                    if let tailBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.tailBottom] {
                        if let rightBackElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightBackElbow] {
                            Line(points: [tailBottom.location, rightBackElbow.location], size: size)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    if let rightBackElbow = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightBackElbow] {
                        if let rightBackKnee = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightBackKnee] {
                            if let rightBackPaw = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.rightBackPaw] {
                                Line(points: [rightBackElbow.location, rightBackKnee.location, rightBackPaw.location], size: size)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    // Connect the tail joints.
                    if let tailBottom = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.tailBottom] {
                        if let tailMiddle = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.tailMiddle] {
                            if let tailTop = animalJoint.animalBodyParts[.tailTop] {
                                Line(points: [tailBottom.location, tailMiddle.location, tailTop.location], size: size)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                                    .fill(Color.orange)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

and a shape to draw line:
// Create a transform that converts the pose's normalized point.
struct Line: Shape {
    var points: [CGPoint]
    var size: CGSize
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let pointTransform: CGAffineTransform =
            .identity
            .translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -1.0)
            .concatenating(.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0))
            .concatenating(.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: points[0])
        for point in points {
            path.addLine(to: point)
        }
        return path.applying(pointTransform)
    }
}

Looking online I saw that it was recommended to change the property cameraView.previewLayer.videoGravity
from
cameraView.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

to
cameraView.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect

and modify
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}

in CameraViewController.swift but it doesn't work for me.
Could you help me understand where I'm wrong?
Thanks!
EDIT:
I changed to Human Detection and remove the toggle in the top of the view (I just need the body track, not the emoji overlay)
Sample images:
Without ignoring safe area
Ignoring Safe area
iPad

I haven’t looked at the sample but this might provide some insight.

Thanks, I tried to follow the advice, starting from .border(Color.orange) but the size is correct. I'm updating the post adding the image, I just switched to human detection and removed the toggle from the sample project.
Tell me if you need me to add more code snippets

I don’t plan on duplicating your issue. But since path is using the given rect you have to make sure it is being given the correct rect

Same concept as this question the parents padding was giving the video player the  available rect.

I added some print() to track the size and rect, it seems correct.
(Probably this sample code provided by Apple was built just for ios wwdc session)

I received an answer from Apple Developer forum.
There are 2 possible solution:

Set

cameraView.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resize

in CameraViewController
but the view will stretch

Pass the video's aspect ratio along to the GeometryReader

DisplayView(animalJoint: animalJoint)
    .overlay {
        GeometryReader { geo in 
         // draw skeleton
         }.aspectRatio(..., contentMode: .fill)
    }
}

Here the complete post:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/764042
